# Etymology of Old French 'escorgier': How does 'bind' evolve to mean 'whip'?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, french

> [scourge (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scourge&allowed_in_frame=0)
> c. 1200, "a whip, lash," from Anglo-French *escorge*, back-formation from Old French *escorgier* ***"to whip,"*** from Vulgar Latin *excorrigiare*, from Latin **ex- "out, off"** (see [ex-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ex-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *corrigia* "thong, shoelace," in this case **"`whip`,"** probably from a Gaulish word related to Old Irish *cuimrech* "fetter," from **PIE root *reig- "to bind"** (see [rig (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rig&allowed_in_frame=0)). ...

I heed the etymological fallacy, but [what are some right ways of interpreting the significance of the PIE root in this etymology, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571). In particular,

1. How did ***reig- "to bind"**  evolve to mean **`whip`** (I refer to the one greyed)?
2. What happened to the prefix **ex- "out, off"**? It doesn't look as if though it evolved, because the italicised states only ***to whip***, NOT ***to whip*** OUT or OFF, whatever  this latter means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sense "bind" gives a noun for a thing you bind with, i.e. a "thong" or "strap"; this in turn comes to mean "whip" because a whip and a thong are similar things; and on this is based a verb meaning "to whip". The prefix *ex-* in Latin doesn't always literally refer to "motion out" -- in some compounds, as presumably here, it can mean something like "thoroughly".